# R populating columns based on previous values

Tags: r, generate-series

I am trying to populate a series like this.

```
                My result                 ACTUAL         Expected       
FWK_SEQ_NBR  a  initial_d   initial_c   b   c   d       b   c   d
914        9.161    131       62        0   62  69      0   62  69
915        9.087    131       0         0   53  78      0   53  78
916        8.772    131       0         0   44  140     0   44  87
917        8.698    131       0         0   0   140     0   35  96
918        7.985    131       0        69   52  139    69   96  35
919        6.985    131       0        78   63  138    78  168   0
920        7.077    131       0       140   126 138    87  247   0
921        6.651    131       0       140   126 138    96  336   0
922        6.707    131       0       139   125 138    35  364   0
```

## Logic

```
a     given
b     lag of d by 4
c     initial c for first week thereafter (c previous row + b current - a current)
d     initial d - c current
```

Here is the code i used

```
DS1 = DS %>% 
mutate(c    = ifelse(FWK_SEQ_NBR == min(FWK_SEQ_NBR), intial_c, 0)   ) %>%
mutate(c    = lag(c) + b - a)) %>% 
mutate(d    = initial_d - c) %>% 
mutate(d    = ifelse(d<0,0,d)) %>%
mutate(b    = shift(d, n=4, fill=0, type="lag"))
```

I am not getting the c right, do you know what i am missing. I have also attached the image of the actual and expected output. Thank you for your help!

[Actual and Expected values Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbRr.png)

## Second Image - Added Product and Store to the list of columns

[Image - Product and Store as the first two columns- please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFIwx.png)

Below is the actual code, I have also copied the image of the expected and actual output. thank you!

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. Please edit to provide sample values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` as applicable and then, what you want the output to be.

Comment: makes a lot more sense now. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, the problem and sequence of operation you listed are correct? You are deriving `b` from `d`, `c` from `b` and `a` where `b` is dependent on `d` and then again `d` from `c`. This will create a recursion calculation problem.

Comment: I was able to implement the c logic fine in excel. for c calculation, i am taking from value of c from previous row and current values of b and a. I tried implementing C in a loop but no luck. thanks for your response.

Comment: What is your sequence of operation? `a` is given. Is it fair to assume `b` get calculated before `c` and `c` before `d`? Can you share your `R` code for `b` and `d`.

Comment: I have added the actual code along with my output and the expected output. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not what I would call reproducible and the code snippet also did not provide much insight on what you were trying to do. However the screen image from excel was very helpful. Here is my solution

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = c(1:9), b = 0, c = 0, d = NA))
c_init = 62
d_init = 131
df$d <- d_init
df$c[1] <- c_init # initial data frame is ready at this stage

iter <- dim(df)[1] # for the loop to run item times

for(i in 1:iter){
  if(i>4){
    df[i, "b"] = df[i-4,"d"] # Calculate b with the lag
  }
 if(i>1){
    df[i, "c"] = df[i-1, "c"] + df[i, "b"] - df[i, "a"] # calc c
  }
  df[i, "d"] <- d_init - df[i, "c"] # calc d
  if(df[i, "d"] < 0) {
    df[i, "d"] <- 0 # reset negative d values
  }
}
```

Comment: One more question, Let's say i have 2 additional variables 'Product' and 'store' in addition to 'FWK_SEQ_NBR' that i need to sequence along to calculate these variables, how would you change this.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, however I think what you are asking is if there were other columns as well that define the rows that need recalculating, how would I go about it? I would split the `df` in two and focus on the subset for improved performance. Once calculated merge it back with the the other part. That's just one approach. If you have an example of an initial and expected data frame, i can suggest with more confidence.

Comment: could you please help with this, In the same problem, I have two other variables Product and Store that i need to use to generate this series. I have tried Nested loop by using a for Store and Product, but it is taking a lot of time. do you know a better way to accomplish this. I have attached the second image for more context. thanks for your help.